# Android Widget does not show in list untill second run

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I am trying to run a widget and i have seen this problem has been discussed in many questions here and every one suggest that a activity should be started so then the app can be shown. I have even started a activity but when i finish the activity , still the widget is not shown.
Here is my manifest . Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mamlambo.imageswidget"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.2" >

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".ImagesWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/imageswidget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".ImagesWidgetConfiguration"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Recycle" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Search" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TabingActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".ImagesWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

            <data android:scheme="images_widget" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/imageswidget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".ImagesWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".CustomReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```